# drawing balls from box without replacemnt

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

In box we have $n$ black and $m$ white balls without replacement. Let's denote

$B_k$  - number of black balls drawed in first $k$ draws

$W_k$ -  same for white ones

Let's assume that we drawed three black balls at the beggining ($B_3=3, W_3=0$). Compute

$\mathbb{P} \left( B_k-W_k \ge 2 \text{ for all k } \in \{ 2,3,\ldots, n+m \} \right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as asking the following question: suppose we have $n-2$ black balls and $m$ white balls, drawn without replacement. What is the probability that we have never drawn more white balls than black. Investigate ballot numbers (see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem)).